# How do I create a LIRC configuration file?

Tags: linux, raspbian, lirc

I'm trying to use Linux Infrared Remote Control LIRC library to record a custom signal from remote control and save it in a file. Then I will use these signals to send it back again through ir tx using raspberry pi
when I run test ir rx `mode2 -d /dev/lirc1` the output seems good .

```
Using driver default on device /dev/lirc1
Trying device: /dev/lirc1
Using device: /dev/lirc1
space 16777215
pulse 9044
space 4463
pulse 601
space 1641
pulse 628
space 532
pulse 575
space 558
pulse 577
space 530
pulse 603
```

But when I open the  `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf` file, this happens:

```
# Type of device controlled
#     (TV, VCR, Audio, DVD, Satellite, Cable, HTPC, ...) :
# Device(s) controlled by this remote:

begin remote

 name  fan
 bits            0
 flags CONST_LENGTH
 eps             0
 aeps            0

 one             0     0
 zero            0     0
 gap          50000
 toggle_bit_mask 0x0
 frequency    38000

     begin codes
         KEY_POWER                0x0
         KEY_0                    0x0
         KEY_1                    0x0
     end codes

end remote
```

All saved keys are zeroes, so how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your LIRC driver is configured and seems ok from this side. However it is worth double checking the driver has been set up correctly as I think this is the problem.

Assuming you are using T95m/T95N remote:

- 0x140 KEY_POWER
- 0x155 KEY_POWER
- 0x101 KEY_0
- 0x14e KEY_1

Try editing your etc/lirc/lircd.conf with the above values running it(blast some IR commands) and seeing if it turns the values back to 0x0 after.

Comment: I tried to edit these values, but this message has appeared
```pi@raspberrypi:~ $ irsend SEND_ONCE fan KEY_POWER
hardware does not support sending
Error running command: Input/output error
```

Comment: Ok so it's not transmitting, you will have to find the remote you are using key table & perhaps also try
editing /etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf and change:
driver          = devinput
to
driver          = default

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you declare the transmitter GPIO pin first then the receiver

like this :
dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=17
dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=18

and i would double check /etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf as  TeeJay suggested
this fixed my problem on raspberrypi 3+